# How to detect if url protocol is http or https in chrome extension development?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following code to detect the url from the browser tab. I want to detect the protocol of that url (is it http or https). How can I do this?

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    console.log(tabs[0].url);// returning the current url of tab     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply split the url on `":"`

```
// protocol will be http or https
var protocol = tabs[0].url.split(":")[0];
```